# __add__ all elements of a list

Tags: python

I'd like to combine a list of class instances of a class for which the `__add__` method is defined.

i.e., I have a list of class instances `L=[A,B,C,D]` and I want their sum `E = A+B+C+D`, but generalized so that instead of the `+` syntax I could do something like `E = sum(L)`.

What function should I use to do that?  Is the `__add__` method adequate, or do I need to define a different class method (e.g. `__iadd__`) in order to accomplish this?

(if this turns out to be a duplicate, how should I be asking the question?)

Comment: @AdamMihalcin `__iadd__` is one of the standard operator methods.

Comment: @Taymon My mistake.  I've deleted the offending comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sum` may want to add numerical values to instances of your class. Define [`__radd__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__radd__) so for example `int` + `Foo(1)` will be defined:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
    def __add__(self, other):
        return self.val + other.val
    def __radd__(self, other):
        return other + self.val

A = Foo(1)
B = Foo(2)
L = [A,B]
print(A+B)
# 3

print(sum(L))
# 3
```

Answer (score 5):

```
import operator
reduce(operator.add, L)
```

Comment: Gah, hit delete.  [Even clicked 'yes' when it asked if I was sure.]  While sum(L) won't work, sum(L, the_zero) will-- `__add__` is getting called, it's simply starting from the default, which is 0.

Comment: Note that in recent version, `sum` disallows strings (in the start element), and all solutions that boil down to repeatedly calling `+` are inefficent for lists, tuples, etc. too -- and for concatenating strings, `str.join` is actively recommended.

Comment: Good answer; +1 but unutbu's more directly answers the question (`__radd__` needs to be defined for `sum` to work).

Answer (score 3):

Ignore my previous answer, it was wrong.

The `reduce` function allows you to apply any binary function or method to all the elements of a sequence. So, you could write:

```
reduce(YourClass.__add__, sequence)
```

If not all objects in the sequence are instances of the same class, then instead use this:

```
import operator
reduce(operator.add, sequence)
```

Or this:

```
reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, sequence)
```

Comment: In the future you might want to edit your answer instead of deleting it and creating a new one.

Comment: Normally I would, but since the old answer was 100% wrong I thought I should delete it.

Comment: You can change it 100%, then :)

Comment: I came for the same problem and found `reduce` to work perfectly.